# Performance issues with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: nvidia

I'm new to linux. I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my USB 3.0 external hard drive. The problem is that Ubuntu takes a long time to boot. Also, when I try to reboot, it gets stuck at the Ubuntu loading screen.

Here are my laptop specs:

- 8GB ram
- Intel i7-6500u 2.5ghz dual core 64bit
- Nvidia GTX 940M
- 256GB SSD
- 1TB external hard drive

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Is this a full install to external drive? Did you partition in advance with gpt and include an ESP - efi system partition? Have you installed nVidia proprietary drivers? May be best to see details, you can run from Ubuntu live installer or any working install:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu onto that drive using the same computer? Have you used Ubuntu on that drive with other computers?

Comment: I did install Ubuntu using the same computer and also did the partition using gpt. Also tried to install the Nvidia drivers, but I'll do that again as well. I haven't tried to run it on my desktop,  but will do that and get back to you.

Comment: @oldfred I tried to get the boot info, but it will not give me the link to the file instead it gives the whole text file:

Comment: Here is the boot-info file:

Comment: Sorry, the file has  too many characters for the comment, any ideas on how to get it to you guys, thanks for the help. I appreciate it very much

Comment: boot-info link:   http://pastebin.com/w7R5xHH7

Comment: this is the link with my external hard drive plugged in thought it'll be helpful : http://pastebin.com/wSreeNrD

Comment: You installed in the 35 year old BIOS/MBR configuration to external. That should work, but you can only dual boot by using UEFI to choose it and may have to turn off UEFI and turn on CSM/BIOS/Legacy in UEFI settings. If you have both USB2 & USB3 ports the USB3 ports should be a bit faster. How long does it take? It will not be anywhere near as fast as an internal SSD. And you left Windows fast start up on. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: @oldfred I had Legacy turned on in bios but i put legacy as boot priority. This did not fix the issue. It takes about 20 secs to load the system and it takes an additional 20 secs after i log on to load the icons

Comment: @chaiT.Rex I was using xorg drivers and when i installed the nvidia drivers i wasn't able to load the system at all, it gave me the message that i was running in low graphics mode. So i had to revert to xorg drivers

Comment: Not sure if 40 sec from USB drive booting in BIOS mode is considered long.

Comment: Hmm I see, Thanks for clearing that up. But there is still a problem with reboot, it get stuck on the loading page and when i press the arrow keys it says reached target shutdown?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Performance cost of running Ubuntu from external hard drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21741/performance-cost-of-running-ubuntu-from-external-hard-drive)

Answer (score 0):

If you installed drivers from nvidia, I would try and uninstalling them.

If you did try to purge them from your install by booting to command-line(recovery-mode) and executing `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`

Before rebooting do a `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` for good practice. If any packages are broken run `sudo apt-get -f install`

It should then fallback to legacy drivers. 
I had more or less this problem on 16.04 and 16.10
Using those drivers immediately fixed it for me.